# How to get current user_id of logged in user

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I just created a php file to update a field in mysql db, my update query is where i have an issue, i want to set 'user_id' to be the user_id of the current user that is logged in so the update will go to the appropriate user. I haven't been able to get this to work. I feel its because i haven't declared the current user earlier in the code, how can i do this?

Here is the line:

```
$sql = "UPDATE wp85_usermeta SET `meta_value` = `meta_value`+65000 WHERE `user_id` = user_id AND `meta_key` = 'mycred_default'"
```

Here is the full code:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "sparyqmr_wp324";
    $password = "(S8p3uV-2t";
    $dbname = "sparyqmr_wp324";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE wp85_usermeta SET `meta_value` = `meta_value`+65000 WHERE `user_id` = user_id AND `meta_key` = 'mycred_default'";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Session variables. Session varibles are globals variables which are stored on the server for each user.

If a user log ins, you can store his userid in a session varible. If the session is started, you can access this varible in all your documents.

You can start a session with:

`session_start();`

You can set a session variable, with the following code:

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = 'your_user';
```

Comment: sessions is a great solution for low-traffic products. once you scale up and add machines, it creates new issues. its better to use something like JWT (a signed token) that can be passed as part of the request, for example, as a cookie, and read independently by each request. you can read more about it here - https://jwt.io/introduction/ . said that, for wordpress specifically, there are probably simple solutions like the one stated in the other answer. i would read their docs to see how to do such things - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/

Answer (score 0):

Logged in user info is in [WP Session Cookies](https://www.cookielawinfo.com/wordpress-cookies-list-why-they-are-used/).

Example:

```
    foreach ($_COOKIE as $k => $v) {
        if ( preg_match( "/wordpress_logged_in/", $k ) ) {
            // DO SOMETHING WITH THIS COOKIE
        } // end if matched login cookie
} // end foreach
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this adding the following to the top of my code

```
require ('wp-blog-header.php');

global $wpdb;

global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

$skrivID = $current_user->ID;
```

using $skrivID later in the code automatically returned the user id of the logged in user